# How to make pdf comments (in e.g. Foxit reader) searchable in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-search, pdf-reader, comments

I can search the content of the pdf itself but I sometimes save the pdf with small notes. Is there a way that I can make these notes searchable with Foxit or another reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install small module to help the [Windows Indexing Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to extract information of PDF files. There is a pretty decent one: [Foxit IFilter](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/ifilter/) (Note: Foxit IFilter is either bundled to Foxit PhantomPDF to be used on a desktop or as a standalone server product). You can also use the one of [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5542) (free).

After you have installed it, the Indexing Service is able to create a searchable index of all of your pdf-files (or at least the ones you have in folders for which you have configured WIS to index content :)). If the pdf get indexed, you are then able to search for content directly in the windows explorer.

Tutorial on how to install an IFilter: http://www.documentsnap.com/how-to-fix-pdf-search-in-windows-7-64-bit/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However the $699 pricetag is a bit high...

Comment: "Adobe currently bundles a 32-bit PDF iFilter with Adobe Acrobat® 11 as well as the free Adobe Reader® 11 software. It uses the Microsoft iFilter interface and allows third-party indexing tools to extract text from Adobe PDF files."

Comment: "The desktop version, which has been bundled to Foxit PhantomPDF 5.2 and later versions, is not a standalone application. And you can get it by installing Foxit PhantomPDF." ... so, it's a bit cheaper than the 699$.

Comment: I don't know what's going on with the pricing of the Foxit iFilter. There are free downloads available online. [Here](http://foxit-pdf-ifilter.software.informer.com/), for instance. I'm not sure what difference there is from buying the $700 version.

Comment: Ah, never mind. Judging by the screenshots, that download is actually the trial version (although it doesn't say that). There's an older version [here](http://www.fileol.com/utilities/foxit-pdf-ifilter-vv2.1.1.1503.html) that's listed as freeware... not sure if that's actually a trial or unrestricted.

Answer (score 1):

- Acrobat Reader can search within annotations.

  - Go to `Edit` -> `Advanced Search`.
  - At the bottom of the popup window, click `Show More Options`.
  - Check the `Include Comments` checkbox.
- Okular searches inline comments, but not pop-up comments.

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I was not clear: I want to search pdf files and comments therein using Windows Explorer. I do not want to perform the search from the open pdf file.

Comment: Oh, okay. I noticed the windows-search tag, but thought it was misapplied. As akira says, you need an iFilter. Have you tried the free Adobe iFilter? I _think_ it works with annotations. The 32-bit version comes bundled with Reader, but for 64-bit you need to [download](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5542) it. Note: you _might_ still need to follow the instructions above to index the annotations. (Not sure if that affects indexing or just search results.) There's also Foxit iFilter, which is meant to be much faster. There do seem to be free downloads available.

Comment: I would have uovoted you but I do not have enough reputation yet. Thank you for your help!